# How to properly import module in javascript with webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

I've got a file my-class.js

```js
class MyClass {
  constructor(container) {
    const myElements = container.querySelectorAll(".class");
    
    for (const myElement of myElements) {
       myElement.addEventlistener("click", this.doThings.bind(this));
    }

  }
  doThings() {
     // do things
  }
}

(() => {
   for (const of document.querySelectorAll(".class-holder")) {
     new MyClass(container);
   }
}
```

that I import in my main.js file with `import "./path-to-file/my-class"`. But I want to export it instead of create a new instance, and then import it in my main.js file.

But if I export with `export { MyClass }` and then import with `import { MyClass } from "./path-to-file/my-class.js"`, I get `MyClass is declared but it's value is never read`. And if I try to run it in my main.js file with `new MyClass();` I get `Cannot read property querySelectorAll of undefined`. How can I properly do the import in my main file so that the code in my-class.js runs correctly?

Comment: I don't see any `export` statement in your code

Comment: You get `MyClass is declared but it's value is never read` because you never use it

Comment: What does this for loop supposed to do? It doesn't do anything. It's just invalid syntax

Comment: @KonradLinkowski No, that was to show what my code looked like, I tried to add `export { MyClass }` instead of `new MyClass(container);`

Comment: I understand that I never use it, but how do I use it correctly?

Comment: `new MyClass(container)`

Comment: I tried that, it gives me `container is not defined`.

Comment: Because you have to declare this variable first. Please try first use this class in the same file, then move it to a separate one,

Comment: Side note: [doing work from a constructor is a practice that most developers avoid](https://tech-blog.cv-library.co.uk/2017/12/12/avoid-work-in-constructors/). It is disconcerting to see `new MyClass(container)` not being assigned to anything.

Comment: @JuanMendes I use `container` to try to make the module not depending on a global scope and to use `container.querySelectorAll` instead of `document`, I'm open to better ways of doing it as I'm trying to learn.

Comment: If I change `container.querySelectorAll` to `document.querySelectorAll` and then import with `import { MyClass }` and then run with `new MyClass();` my code works. So my problem seems to be with the `container` parameter.

Comment: Typically, you would just assign container to a property in the constructor and you would have another method that would hook up the actual listeners, and potentially another method to remove the listeners.